# Segmentation Fault in stl_vector.h header

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault

I face a very interesting problem with arrays when I use OpenSceneGraph library (OSG 3.0; GCC 4.7.1; C::B 13.12 ). It's declared that Vec3Array class type is derived from vector class, so normally one'd expect the same functionality and same inheritance behaviour of Vec3Array with the vector class.

I have 3 Vec3Array lists 1st for the vertices, 2nd for normals and 3rd for the indices. I create the 1st and fill it with values calling the proper push_back function, then I create the 2nd value and fill the values, but if I want to refer back to 1st list ( with `cnt = obj_vertices->size();` code) then program throws an exception.

What is wrong here ?

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Vec3Array> obj_vertices  = new osg::Vec3Array; ////1st LIST 
obj_vertices->push_back(osg::Vec3d(-3.0000, 0.0, 4.0000 ));
obj_vertices->push_back(osg::Vec3d( 3.0000,0.0, 4.0000  ));
.......
osg::Vec3d vec1, vec2, vec3;
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Vec3Array> normals = new osg::Vec3Array; // 2nd LIST 
vec1[0] = 0; vec1[1] = -1; vec1[3] =0;
vec2[0] = 1; vec2[1] = 0; vec2[3] = 0;
vec3[0] = 0; vec3[1] = -1; vec3[3] =0;
normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);
normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);
normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);normals->push_back(vec1);

normals->push_back(vec2);normals->push_back(vec2);normals->push_back(vec2);normals->push_back(vec2);
normals->push_back(vec2);normals->push_back(vec2);normals->push_back(vec2);normals->push_back(vec2);

normals->push_back(vec3);normals->push_back(vec3);normals->push_back(vec3);normals->push_back(vec3);

cnt = obj_vertices->size(); /// EXCEPTION IS TRIGGERED HERE 
.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vec1[0] = 0; vec1[1] = -1; vec1[3] =0;
```

The last index in a 3D vector is 2, not 3.

Comment: Isn't the compiler supposed to throw an exception at the time of trying to assign the wrong indexed value in `vec1[3] =0;`? Otherwise we almost have a no chance to catch it.

Comment: @SonyaBlade - No.  C++ doesn't work that way.  If a `throw` has not been explicitly coded by the library, then no exception is thrown.  You will just enter the world of "undefined behavior", where anything can happen.

Comment: @SonyaBlade: The C++ standard library rarely uses exceptions to report errors. And in the scope of C++, this is a good thing. Exceptions in C++ should *not* be used to make up for programming errors, and an illegal vector index happens at such a low level that it must be a programming error, i.e. that your *code* is wrong. Nevertheless, the compiler is allowed to "fill" the UB by implementing its own checks. Chances are it will use an internal `assert` to crash the program when the index is out of range.